# Possible to remove p tags from a table cell in Wygwam

Tags: wygwam

I have a problem that occasionally a `<p>` tag is being added to a table cell, usually when someone pastes something into it.

Is there a way to remove that `<p>` and just have the cell be an empty `<td>` or `<th>`, ideally without editing the source?

Is there an option that could be added through the advanced settings?

Comment: When they're pasting, do they use the "paste as plain text" option?

Answer (score 3):

If the reason is appearance, you can remove any margin/padding formatting with css, like:
`table p {padding:0; margin:0}`
Or you can add specific classes to the styling menu of wygwam for tables, for a more fine grained control over styling tables.

Answer (score 0):

what about using one of the HTML stripper add-ons?

You can find quite a few [here](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=strip&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2) on Devot:ee.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it easily. A custom extension to parse the text on submission might do it, but the issue is CKEditor forces <p> tags around pretty much every inline element. You're better off just leaving it and changing the styles like GDMac suggested.